# Proper use of 'clear' property (related to floated elements)

Tags: css, css-float

I have a few doubts with the `clear:x;` property.

Preludes: I need to make a list, and the elements must be placed as a grid. Also, I need to make it compatible with IE7 or greater.

Here's my HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>A</li>
    <li>B</li>
    <li>C</li>
    <li>D</li>
</ul>
```

And the CSS (ul + li are the trick for emulating `nth-of-type`; in the real code I have about ten elements by row):

```
ul {list-style:none; margin:0; padding:0;}
ul li{background:pink; border:1px solid red; height:1em; width:1em; float:left; margin:0 .2em .2em 0; padding:.3em}
ul li + li + li {clear:left;}
ul li + li + li +li {clear:none;}
```

This works well. [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/28HbA/).

BUT, in first place my intuition makes me put a `clear:right` in the second `li`. But that code doesn't work, here's [the corresponding fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/28HbA/1/).

Why this doesn't work? It isn't expected that the second `li` will clear the third `li` at his right?

Comment: a class `.clear { clear:both; }` will work - now you just have to create a div after the `li` element like this `<div class="clear"></div>` and there you go :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The clear:right property doesn't prevent elements from being placed in
>   that space after the cleared element. It prevents the element from
>   being placed where there are already elements floated to the that
>   direction before it - ahruss

You are using a `float:left;` thats when you need to use a `clear:left;` 
If you are using a `float:right;` than you can cause a line break with a `clear:right;` 
You can check out this 2 behavior here Here's [a **Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/28HbA/7/)

So when you use a `clear:left` on the `"C" li` then it will cause a **line break**.
You could also use a `clear:both;` to cause a **line break**. 
or you just use a `<br />`.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because `clear` doesn't clear elements that come after the element in document order. There are no elements in your fiddle that are both: positioned on right-hand side of your element where `clear: right` is set and come before that element in document order.

I hope this clarifies your question :-)